# Are there ROS2 fiducial markers

Tags: navigation, ros2, markers

I have not been able to get any marker nodes to build for Humble.
The ones I've tried are riddled with depreciated OpenCV code.

Comment: It would help to name the packages you tried but did not work on Humble.